# Querying an imported range works until I add any condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Here's a `QUERY` that works:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[key omitted]", "'FORM RESPONSES 1'!A1:G999"),
       "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7",
       1)
```

This is just the same, but I added a "where" and a condition:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[key omitted]", "'FORM RESPONSES 1'!A1:G999"),
       "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 where Col1 <> 'foo'",
       1)
```

When I run the second query, instead of showing all rows of the source spreadsheet, only the first row is shown. There is no "foo" in my data, so all rows should be shown, just like in the first. I looked at examples, and this seems to be valid syntax.

What do you suppose is happening?

Comment: does column A contain text or numerical values?

Comment: You nailed it. I was querying for text in a timestamp column -- I just thought that any column would do for testing, as long as it didn't contain "foo". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `QUERY`, try `FILTER`, like this:

```
=IFERROR(filter(
    IMPORTRANGE("[Key Omitted]","'Form Responses 1'!A1:G999"),
    NOT(IFERROR(
        SEARCH(
            "foo",
            IMPORTRANGE("[Key Omitted]","'Form Responses 1'!A1:A999")
        )
    ))
))
```

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but putting my key in that and trying it got me a #REF! error: "Circular dependency detected."  Looking at it, nothing circular leaps out at me...

Comment: My fault. I corrected the formula. Please try again.

Comment: If this worked for you, could you please approve the answer by checking the star? Thanks.